# Swift Playgrounds on MacOS - Contacts access is promoted, but has no effect

Tags: swift-playground, cncontact

If you follow the examples for [permitting your playground Contacts access](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift-playgrounds/project-capabilities), it works in Playgrounds/iPadOS, but not on Playgrounds/macOS

The prompt appears, and no error is returned, but System Preferences do not show any change, and there is no created contact, etc. (There is also no error returned, because at that level, it seems to think it was successful?)